# Using VBA to write from one access table to another, not SQL

Tags: vba

In Access I am trying to write some code that will simply copy all the rows from one table into another.

I am trying not to use SQl, this is in the hope that having VB do this will be a lot quicker, at the moment the query used to do this job takes an hour.

It breaks at the first record, "record is deleted". Although the table where the record is exporting from has records in it.

I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas about how to fix this?

Or if I'm going about this the wrong way?

```
Public Sub ClientsImport()
Dim rs As Recordset, rsIN As Recordset
Dim db As Database

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblDIFCClients_Import2", dbOpenDynaset)
Set rsIN = db.OpenRecordset("tblDIFCClients_import_IN", dbOpenDynaset)

Logit "Start:tblDIFCClients_import..."
DoCmd.RunSQL ("delete * from tblDIFCClients_import_IN")
Logit "... Cleared holding table..."
CurrentDb.Execute ("qryMatch_TblClients1")
Logit "... Grabbed from Server..."
Logit "... Updating Live table..."
DoCmd.RunSQL ("delete * from tblDIFCClients_import2")
Logit "Append Clients"

rsIN.MoveFirst
With rs
    Do Until rsIN.EOF
    .AddNew
    ![fldDIFCClientsRAWID] = rsIN![fldDIFCClientsRAWID]
    ![fldClientID] = rsIN![fldClientID]
    ![fldClientname] = rsIN![fldClientname]
    ![fldStyleSheet] = rsIN![fldStyleSheet]
    ![fldcustomjs] = rsIN![fldcustomjs]
    ![fldBannerImage] = rsIN![fldBannerImage]
    ![fldLogoImage] = rsIN![fldLogoImage]
    ![fldVanityURL] = rsIN![fldVanityURL]
    ![fldDescription] = rsIN![fldDescription]
    ![fldBusinessNumber] = rsIN![fldBusinessNumber]
    ![fldBasePrimaryColour] = rsIN![fldBasePrimaryColour]
    ![fldDefaultForwardingEmail] = rsIN![fldDefaultForwardingEmail]
    ![fldHasPFPs] = rsIN![fldHasPFPs]
    ![fldHasMicrosite] = rsIN![fldHasMicrosite]
    ![fldHasEvents] = rsIN![fldHasEvents]
    ![fldDateTimeStamp] = rsIN![fldDateTimeStamp]
    ![fldModified] = rsIN![fldModified]
    ![fldDownloaded] = rsIN![fldDownloaded]
    ![fldIgnore] = rsIN![fldIgnore]
    .Update
    rsIN.MoveNext
End With

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
rsIN.Close
Set rsIN = Nothing

Logit "End: Clients Import"
Logit ""
Debug.Print "Done:Clients"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I really don't think that looping through the recordset is going to be faster than copying the table via SQL.

As it is, your code is deleting the content of the table you are copying **from** before reading, hence the `row is deleted` error.  You get a recordset from `tblDIFCClients_import_IN`:

```
Set rsIN = db.OpenRecordset("tblDIFCClients_import_IN", dbOpenDynaset)
```

the delete its contents:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL ("delete * from tblDIFCClients_import_IN")
```

then try to read from it:

```
Do Until rsIN.EOF
```

You are executing `qryMatch_TblClients1` in between.  Does this populate `tblDIFCClients_import_IN`?  If so, and that's what you're expecting to be loaded into `tblDIFCClients_Import2`, then simplying moving the `Set rsIN = db.OpenRecordset...` line to occur **after** the call to execute `qryMatch_TblClients1` should fix it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I'll try those things out, I thought it would be something simple. I'm a bit of a newbie to this so you can understand the error! thanks